# Image on Ionic2/3 app html page

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

In `Ionic2/3` `Typescript` application:

I got display of my image(s) successfully this way:

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="{{imgPath}}">
      </ion-avatar>
    </ion-item>
```

But it is blank squares if I put it in `ion-img`:

```
    <ion-img src="{{imgPath}}"></ion-img>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the image dimensions. I made a simple example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-kpkk5u)

```
  <ion-img width="80" height="80" src="{{test}}"></ion-img>
```

in ts file:

```
test ="https://i.imgur.com/FMo96fW.jpg";
```

Comment: Hello, I got same result